# Uncaught Invariant Violation: ReactCompositeComponent.render(): A valid ReactComponent must be returned

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, coffeescript, react-rails

Inside the render method of react, I am trying to render some children on the basis of state variable. Quoted below is the piece of code for the same:

```
  render: ->
    if @state.edit
      @adminForm()
    else
      @adminRow()
    if @state.showModal
      React.createElement AdminDeleteModal, email: @props.admin.email, handleOK: @handleDelete, handleCancelDelete: @hidePopUpModal
```

This is leading me to an error: `"Uncaught Invariant Violation: ReactCompositeComponent.render(): A valid ReactComponent must be returned. You may have returned undefined, an array or some other invalid object."`

But, when I shift this rendering part of the `AdminDeleteModal` to the end of the @adminRow() method it works:

```
  adminRow: ->
    dom.tr
      className: 'row'
      dom.td
        className: "col-md-6"
        @props.admin.email
      dom.td
        className: "col-md-6 text-right"
        dom.a
          className: 'glyphicon glyphicon-edit text-primary'
          onClick: @handleToggle
        dom.a
          className: 'glyphicon glyphicon-trash text-danger deletethis'
          data: { title: 'Delete Admin?' ,confirm: "Are you sure you want to delete User #{@props.admin.email}?"}
          onClick: @showPopUpModal
      if @state.showModal
        React.createElement AdminDeleteModal, email: @props.admin.email, handleOK: @handleDelete, handleCancelDelete: @hidePopUpModal
```

Although, this gives rise to another problem of having div inside tr, leading to the following warning:

```
Warning: validateDOMNesting(...): <div> cannot appear as a child of <tr>. See (unknown) > tr > (unknown) > div.
```

**UPDATE:** Updated the code with the suggestions below

```
  render: ->
    if @state.edit
      @adminForm()
    else
      @adminRow()
    if @state.showModal
      dom.tr null,
        dom.td null,
          React.createElement AdminDeleteModal, email: @props.admin.email, handleOK: @handleDelete, handleCancelDelete: @hidePopUpModal
```

Comment: Also you need a `<td>` inside of a `tr` not `div` put the div inside of the `td`

Comment: yes, that worked without error, indentation problem in coffeescript. But how do I proceed for the first one, I encounter such problems often.

Comment: It looks like you are just returning a `tr` without the proper parent element. Am I wrong?

Comment: looks like you were correct, I added the tr+td as parent. But, still it didn't work for me.

Comment: What is the parent of the `tr` is it a `tbody` or a `table`?

Comment: what happens if you take out `if @state.showModal`?

Comment: Igues, it would be rendered properly, but that's not what I want. let me check once!

Comment: Strange thing happens when I move it out of the condition. the first two conditions doesn't seem to work. Neither @adminForm() nor the @adminRow is rendered. Only AdminDeleteModal is rendered

Comment: Seems like there can be only one if else if ladder inside the render statement, otherwise it won't work.

Comment: Did you fix your problem? What happens when you abstract the first conditional in your render to a function call?

Comment: I couldn't fix the problem, used some workaround. But still I'd like to know the solution to this problem